# transformar de lenguaje funcional a iterativo

Tags: estructuras-de-datos, programación-funcional

Necesito transformar este código de funcional a iterativo. Estoy empezando en java.

```
public static boolean ejercicio1_func(List<String> ls, Predicate<String> pS, 
            Predicate<Integer> pI, Function<String,Integer> f){
            return ls.stream()
            .filter(pS)
            .map(f)
            .anyMatch(pI);
            }
```

> Datos de Entrada:
> // El predicado sobre String devuelve cierto si dicho String contiene alguna vocal abierta (es decir, a, e ó o)
> // El predicado sobre Integer devuelve cierto si ese entero es par
> // La función String -> Integer devuelve la longitud de la cadena
> Ingreso
> Ingresos
> Ingreso,Ingresos
> ejercicios,practica,propuesta
> pim,pam,pum
> cadena,recomendar,definir
> elemento,implementar,sol
> ala,map,public,static
> Aplicación, Rod, Palomitas de maíz, Machine, Pizza, Hormigas, Ingresos, Ayuda, Celebración, Hijo, Ejemplo, Tres, Significación, Gancho, Mujeres, Gracias, Aprobación, Extensión, Ropa, Rey, Ansiedad, Guante, Carne, Volumen, Llave, Unidad, Lectura, Locket, Necesidad, Tela, Reunión, Parche, Tanque, Entrada.

La respuesta es un boolean true or false.

Comment: Puedes agregar ejemplos de los parametros y ejemplos del resultado? No parece complejo pero sin casos de prueba es difícil dar una solución

Comment: Ya lo he editado, además hay que añadir esos predicados